# How to disable Apple WatchApp targets while running iOS application with a particular build configuration?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, apple-watch, buildconfiguration

Currently I have watch app targets in my project. But a library added to this watchapp targets was build for device only. So I cannot build the watchapp target in simulator. In my project I am using multiple build configuration. So I want to enable the watchapp while taking production buils for actual device. While running the iOS app in Simulator , the watchapp target is building along with iOS app, since it is added in the target dependancy section. So how can I avoid the watchapp target while running app in simulator ? If yes, is it possible to disable the watchapp for a particular build configuration ?